# StackExchange.Redis Time out

Tags: c#, redis, timeout, signalr, stackexchange.redis

I'm getting this exception when large number of requests sent to server at the same time:

`Timeout performing GET 106, inst: 1, mgr: ProcessReadQueue, err: never, queue: 3, qu: 0, qs: 3, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 234, ar: 1, clientName: AMIN, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/localhost:6379, keyHashSlot: 8597, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=0,Free=8191,Min=4,Max=8191)`

But I don't understand what does it mean.

Although I have changed Timeout time and Retry in Redis Configurations, still there is a Timeout exception. I think it's a kind of bug in the client. The exception happens instantly without event waiting for Timeout time.

Here is Code that cause Timeout Exception :

`await Groups.Remove(ConnectionIdDatabase.StringGet(userToken), $"{ChannelTypes.Active}");`

`await Groups.Add(ConnectionIdDatabase.StringGet(userToken), $"{ChannelTypes.Losers}");`

I'm using SignalR Groups and `StringGet(userToken)` is getting user `connectionId` from Redis.

Thanks

Comment: I have set the `ConnectTimeout=10000000,ConnectRetry=100` but still getting error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stackexchange.Redis timeouts & socketfailures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811020/stackexchange-redis-timeouts-socketfailures)

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Timeouts.md may be worth a read.

Comment: Most possible reason for this is Socket failure. Set some value to `KeepAlive` property while creating a connection to Redis server. For more details about `KeepAlive` property, you can check here: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html

Comment: I have fixed the problem by just changin to `async` api in that lines. `await Groups.Remove(await ConnectionIdDatabase.StringGetAsync(userToken), $"{ChannelTypes.Active}");` , I have no clue why this fixed the issue.